# reading in files line by line and storing the content of each line in a list for further processing

Tags: python

I have 2 lists generated file1 & file2 (where all the letter are random value number).
line in each file is value for same object.

for example object 1 has the following values, all coming from line 1 for all the 2 files

```
  object1:  
    a, b, c, d, e, f
    g, h, i, j, k, l

$ cat file1
a, b, c, d, e, f  # line1 - object1
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f

$ cat file2
g, h, i, j, k, l # line1 - object1
g, h, i, j, k, l
g, h, i, j, k, l
g, h, i, j, k, l
g, h, i, j, k, l
g, h, i, j, k, l
```

Now I have a script that have some list that need to have the value coming from these 2 files in a loop

```
daytime = now.strftime("%A")
varlist1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
varlist2 = [g, h, i, j, k, l]
static1 = [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday]

for li1,li2,st1 in zip(varlist1, varlist2, static1)
    if (li1 != 0 and li2 == 0 and daytime == st1):
        print "Go"
    else:
        print "NoGo"
```

I need to read the file line by line and pass the variable from the file in the list varlist1,varlist2, then process each line of the files in the loop

what is the best way to accomplish this. I wasn't able to find a quick way to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: "I wasn't able to find a quick way to achieve this?" - if you have working code to do this that you believe could be improved, then this question should asked on Code Review. :)

Comment: Alternatively, if it isn't working, please explain more clearly precisely how it is failing to meet your spec.

Comment: `static1 = [Sunday,...` is no working code. I guess you mean `static1 = ['Sunday',`. Please provide working examples.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have working code as I didn't know how to start. I just started learning python few weeks ago so I am still learning. Timgeb provided me working solution for my problem. many thanks for your support (yes, the static is configured with 'Sunday' ....sorry for the typo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to read the file line by line and pass the variable from the file in the list varlist1,varlist2, then process each line of the files in the loop

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but I can give you a demo which should be easily adjustable to suit your needs. I'm also assuming that `a`, `b`, ... are supposed to be integers for this demo. You can process the files line by line like this:

```
f1 = open('file1', 'r')
f2 = open('file2', 'r')

for i in range(3): # your actual conditions go here
    # read in next line from each of the files and store them in a list of ints
    varlist1 = f1.readline().strip().split(', ')
    varlist1 = [int(x) for x in varlist1] # use float(x) here if a,b,... are floats
    varlist2 = f2.readline().strip().split(', ')
    varlist2 = [int(x) for x in varlist2] # use float(x) here if g,h,... are floats
    # do something more interesting with varlist1, varlist2 here
    # than just printing them
    print(varlist1)
    print(varlist2)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

**However**, instead of processing the files line by line, I would prepare all the varlists like this:

```
with open('file1', 'r') as f1:
    data1 = f1.read().splitlines()
with open('file2', 'r') as f2:
    data2 = f2.read().splitlines()

varlists1 = [[int(x) for x in y.split(', ')] for y in data1] # or float(x) ...
varlists2 = [[int(x) for x in y.split(', ')] for y in data2]
```

Now you can do something like:

```
for varlist1, varlist2 in zip(varlists1, varlists2):
    for li1,li2,st1 in zip(varlist1, varlist2, static1):
        # your code here
```

Comment: I'd use `.strip()` instead of `.strip('\n')`, in case the file uses Windows newline mode: `\r\n`. The side effect (desirable?) is that it also removes trailing white space.

Comment: Hi Timegeb, I used the second code and it works as expected. I can get variable from the file and process the data. - many thanks for your help

Comment: @Davidmh thanks, I edited the strip() in. however, readlines() will leave you with the '\n' characters, read().splitlines() will not